# Returning last value of a column filtered by name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like this :

```
DATE,OPTION,SELL,BUY,DEAL
2015-01-01 11:00:01, blah1,0,1,open
2015-01-01 11:00:01, blah2,0,1,open
2015-01-01 11:00:01, blah3,0,1,open
2015-01-01 11:00:02, blah1,0,1,open
2015-01-01 11:00:02, blah2,0,1,open
2015-01-01 11:00:02, blah3,0,1,open
```

I read it in pandas using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_data)
```

no problem there .

How would you return the **last** *"SELL"* value of *"blah2"* ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group it by OPTION and get last row of a given group as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

grouped_df = df.groupby('OPTION')

print(grouped_df.get_group(' blah2').tail(1))
```

This gives:

```
4  2015-01-01 11:00:02   blah2     0    1  open
```

Answer (score 1):

`(df[df['OPTION'] == 'blah2']).tail(1)['SELL']`

to get the last sell value for all options:

`df[['SELL','OPTION']].groupby("OPTION").apply(lambda x: x.tail(1))`

Answer (score 0):

b[b['OPTION']==' blah2'].iloc[-1]['SELL']

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenience method [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last) that can be called on a groupby object, this returns the last value of each group, we can then filter this df on index value:

```
In [75]:

gp = df.groupby('OPTION').last()
gp
Out[75]:
                       DATE  SELL  BUY  DEAL
OPTION                                      
 blah1  2015-01-01 11:00:02     0    1  open
 blah2  2015-01-01 11:00:02     0    1  open
 blah3  2015-01-01 11:00:02     0    1  open
In [76]:

gp[gp.index == ' blah2']
Out[76]:
                       DATE  SELL  BUY  DEAL
OPTION                                      
 blah2  2015-01-01 11:00:02     0    1  open
```